# Vertical misalignment in second last tabu column heading

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu

Even if frowned upon, I'd like to keep the vertical lines. Nevertheless, in the following MWE i get a misalignment in the heading. Once towards the top, once towards the bottom - I added a line in the picture for clarification. Increasing the cell width to keep the heading in one line in the first example does not solve the problem. Question: How do I achieve vertical alignment in tabu-environment across all columns?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \vspace{2ex}
    \centering
    {\tabulinesep=1.2mm
        \begin{tabu}spread 0pt{|X[1cm]|X[-2.5cm]|X[-2cm]|}\hline\hline
            \textbf{Jahr}&\textbf{Plätze insgesamt}&\textbf{Plätze besetzt}\\ \hline
            2010&579.564&559.959\\ \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabu}}
    \end{table} 


\begin{table}[!htb]
    \vspace{2ex}
    \centering
    {\tabulinesep=1.2mm
    \begin{tabu}spread 0pt{|X[1cm]|X[1cm]|X[-1cm]|X[-2cm]|}\hline\hline
    \textbf{Jahrgang}&\textbf{Hauptschule}&\textbf{Realschule}&\textbf{Studienberechtigung}\\ \hline
    2010 &  4 \% &  67 \% & 29 \% \\ \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabu}}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT (As I can not yet comment): 
1)
The link provided by Salim Bou deals with the problem of alignment in multi-line X[m]-tables. I ran across that solution, but the problem outlined here occures even in one-lined (headings of) tables.

2)
The solution provided by gernot works (!) and is quickly to implement but has a drawback I'd like to point out:
In my MWE `Jahr` needs a `\dstrut` as well, as soon as the table is expanded. Furthermore, I had to use several iterations to identify each column in need of a downward extender - this quickly gets out of hand in a longer document.

3)
The solution of egreg has the additional benefit of allowing to be placed in a `\newenvironment` to fix this problem on the fly.

```
%Mytable with three arguments
%#1 - Label
%#2 - Ref
%#3 - dynamic number of columns

%example for a table with two columns: 
%\begin{mt}
% {Number of things in this case over the years}{tab:things_yrs}{2}
%1&2\\ \hline
%3&4\\ \hline
%\end{mt}

\newenvironment{mt}[4]{
\begin{table}[!htb]
\vspace{2ex}
\caption[#1]{#2}
\label{#3}
\centering
\tabulinesep=1.2mm
\begin{tabu}{|*#4{X[-1cm]<{\unskip\strut}|}}\hline\hline}   
{\hline\hline
\end{tabu}
\end{table}}
```

Comment: Related [A vertical alignment problem in tabu environment with X](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26212/a-vertical-alignment-problem-in-tabu-environment-with-xm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem: `tabu` doesn't add a `\strut` at the end of a cell in an `X` column. The second table doesn't suffer from the issue, because there *is* a `\strut` at the beginning.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\tabulinesep=1.2mm

\begin{tabu} spread 0pt{
  |X[1cm]<{\unskip\strut}|
   X[-2.5cm]<{\unskip\strut}|
   X[-2cm]<{\unskip\strut}|
}
\hline
\textbf{Jahr} & \textbf{Plätze insgesamt} & \textbf{Plätze besetzt} \\
\hline
2010          & 579.564                   & 559.959                 \\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{table} 


\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\tabulinesep=1.2mm

\begin{tabu} spread 0pt{|X[1cm]|X[1cm]|X[-1cm]|X[-2cm]|}
\hline
\textbf{Jahrgang} & \textbf{Hauptschule} & \textbf{Realschule} & \textbf{Studienberechtigung}\\
\hline
2010              & 4\%                  & 67\%                & 29\% \\
\hline
\end{tabu}

\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The differences in vertical alignment are due to the fact that `insgesamt` extends below the baseline, while `besetzt` does not. So the height of `Plätze insgesamt` is slightly greater than the one of `Plätze besetzt`. The same for `Realschule` (has no downward extender).

The simplest solution is to define an invisble downward extender

```
\newcommand\dstrut{\vphantom{g}}
```

and to add it after `besetzt` and `Realschule`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\dstrut{\vphantom{g}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htb]
    \vspace{2ex}
    \centering
    {\tabulinesep=1.2mm
        \begin{tabu}spread 0pt{|X[1cm]|X[-2.5cm]|X[-2cm]|}\hline\hline
            \textbf{Jahr}&\textbf{Plätze insgesamt}&\textbf{Plätze besetzt\dstrut}\\ \hline
            2010&579.564&559.959\\ \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabu}}
    \end{table} 


\begin{table}[!htb]
    \vspace{2ex}
    \centering
    {\tabulinesep=1.2mm
    \begin{tabu}spread 0pt{|X[1cm]|X[1cm]|X[-1cm]|X[-2cm]|}\hline\hline
    \textbf{Jahrgang}&\textbf{Hauptschule}&\textbf{Realschule\dstrut}&\textbf{Studienberechtigung}\\ \hline
    2010 &  4 \% &  67 \% & 29 \% \\ \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabu}}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tabu` should have inserted these `struts` itself, but it has been removed according to the doc to avoid a problem. ("Modification of `\@finalstrut` (“null-rule” added) to avoid problems with \columncolor.") I have had more annoying effects because of this change.